# Using reflect, how to create struct "type" dynamically?

Tags: go, reflection

Consider the following struct :

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) foo() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Using reflect I would like to generate a custom struct type that overrides a set of methods.
When doing the work manually what I want to do is :

```
type Edit struct{
    Foo
}

func (e *Edit) foo() {
    e.Foo.foo()
    fmt.Println("World")
}
```

But instead of writing this manually, I would like to make a function that does such override automatically for any given struct.

---

I know that I can instantiate a struct using :

```
res := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(origin))
```

but in this situation, we can't edit methods.

So how with reflect can I create a struct type that wraps an existing type like explained above?

Comment: Doing things like this at runtime is not particularly compatible with Go. This might be a good use case for a generator though, see `go generate`.

Comment: @Adrian: thanks, though if that's not the case, I'm not sure what other answer there could be.

Comment: Indeed theses questions aren't related to what I want. And ideally I'd want to avoid code generation

Comment: Why do you want to avoid code generation? Go does not support creating methods at runtime. Your options are limited.

Comment: Because this is for a library. So I'd like to avoid forcing the library users to use code-gen. This may be impossible though

Comment: Are the methods signatures known, or are they determined at runtime?

Comment: @ThunderCat Methods signature is known. But they don't have a predifined name. I already managed to extract a `[]reflect.Method` list of methods I want to override

Comment: In the end, I used `go generated` combined with `go/parser` and `dave/jennifer/jen`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something extremely similar to what you are asking for using [Method Values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values). You could do something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    sayHelloAgain func()
}

func (f *Foo) SayHello() { 
    fmt.Print("Hello,")
    f.sayHelloAgain() 
}

func main() {
    edit := struct{Foo}{}
    edit.sayHelloAgain = func(){ fmt.Println(" World!") }
    edit.SayHello()

}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XTlGOj5TWBw)

As you can see, you can create an anonymous struct which will be able to call the `SayHello` function, which then calls the receiver's dynamically set `sayHelloAgain` method.

I think this will be the closest you will get to your goal, and works as you requested (without `relection`)

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but this doesn't really fit with what I want to achieve